# pip3 install h5py does not work for pyhton3, because h5py is available for python2.7

Tags: python-3.x, pip, h5py

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 installed. I want to use `h5py` in both versions.

However, if I type

```
pip3 install h5py
```

it says

```
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /home/veronika/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/veronika/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from h5py)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in /home/veronika/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from h5py)
```

and with Python 3 it cannot import `h5py`.

Any ideas for fixing this?

Comment: That is a bit funny. Can you list the output of `ls -l \`which pip3\`` and of `echo $PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: I fixed it with deleting h5py, and reinstalling with pip3....I think, or probably I manually copied/paste things. Very bad, I know....But this screwed my spyderIDE for python2. --> not recommended

Comment: ls -l `which pip3` gives -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 283 Dez 18 13:42 /usr/local/bin/pip3; $PYTHONPATH gives bash: :/home/veronika/gimli/gimli/python: No such file or directory

Comment: That is not very helpful, at least not to me. I have added the `pip` tag, maybe somebody else can be of more help?!

Answer (score 0):

Try tell pip what Python version you want to install the package for:
Ex.:
python3 -m pip install h5py